# Is there any significance to the Earths' numbers?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse

The "Crisis on Infinity Earths" event has introduced so many Earths to the Arrowverse. But do the numbers have any significance? Some obvious ones:

**Earth-666:** Lucifer's earth [666 = Devil] 
**Earth-66:** Based on the old '66 Batman year (1966) 
**Earth-89:** Tim Burton's Batman year (1989) 
**Earth-90:** The old Flash show year (1990)

What about the others?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Earth 38: Supergirl

Might be a nod to the debut of Superman (1938) as mentioned in [another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/64301/1190).

## Earth 16: Future Oliver

The debut episode of future Oliver was in Legends of Tomorrow during first season (2016)

## Earth-99: Future evil Batman

Might be a nod to DCAU (Batman Beyond premiered in 1999)

## Earth-75 Dead Superman

Issue #75 when Doomsday killed Superman.

## Earth-167 Smallville

The number 167 is a nod to the show's producers Alfred Gough and Miles Millar both being born in 1967. [source](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-167)

## Earth-96 Brandon Routh Superman

Must be a reference to [Kingdom Come](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Come_(comics)) (1996)

## Earth 203 Bird of Prey

Birds of Prey (TV series) ended on 2003

## Earth-X

Based on comics and numbered similarly

## Earth-18 Active Lazarus pit

In comics, it was wild west earth. We only see Jonah Hex (Not part of comics earth 18) who is a western hero.

---

Pending:

## Earth-74

## Earth 9: DC Universe's Titans

---

Black Lightning and Nash Wells/Pariah earth is not numbered